# jQuery Accordion - hover trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there any way to open this accordion using class on hover? (e.g. ".accordion--hover" or data-on-hover)

I tried to add the `.open` class on hover and it didn't work for me.

Thanks for any solution.

https://vctrfrnndz.github.io/jquery-accordion/

```
<div data-accordion data-on-hover>
  <div data-control>Control</div>
  <div data-content>
    <div>Row</div>
    <div>Row</div>
    <div>Row</div>
  </div>
</div>

$('.accordion').accordion({
  "transitionSpeed": 400
});
```

Comment: If it's a JS / jQuery plugin - than only using JS listeners. Eeeventually, if you inspect elements and you recognize some class and its stylings, than you can replicate those styles and add them on CSS `:hover` but that's just a theory on some seemingly silly jQuery plugin...

Comment: https://gist.github.com/wtarr/5860398

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are ok with custom solution, then go with it, or if you really want to go with the plugin solution then try firing open and close events of the accordion plugin mentioned in its documentation.

**Events**
**accordion.open** fires when any accordion opens

**accordion.close** fires when any accordion closes

Fire **open** event on mouseEnter and fire **close** event on mouseLeave

find my custom solution below if this works for you

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.accordionHeader').on('mouseenter',function(){
    $(this).find('.accordionContent').slideDown();
  });
  $('.accordionHeader').on('mouseleave',function(){
    $(this).find('.accordionContent').slideUp();
  });
});
```

```css
.accordionContent {
  display: none;
}
.accordionWrapper {margin-bottom: 50px;}
.accordionHeader {padding: 10px;border: 1px solid;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordionWrapper">
  <div class="accordionHeader">
    Hover Me
  <div class="accordionContent">
    Content Go here 
    <div>Row</div>
    <div>Row</div>
    <div>Row</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
<div class="accordionWrapper">
  <div class="accordionHeader">
    Hover Me
  <div class="accordionContent">
    Content Go here 
    <div>Row</div>
    <div>Row</div>
    <div>Row</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
<div class="accordionWrapper">
  <div class="accordionHeader">
    Hover Me
  <div class="accordionContent">
    Content Go here 
    <div>Row</div>
    <div>Row</div>
    <div>Row</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: and if this helps you, don't forget to mark it as right answer

Comment: It works exactly the way I wanted it to. Thank you very much!